# "do you mean" google type search but on string, not just one word

Tags: php

I'm using the following to check spelling on words entered into a search:

```
class GDYM {

public $language = 'en';

/**
 * Google Search for PDA (because it's smaller)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $_url = 'http://google.com/pda?q=%s&hl=%s';

/**
 * Use Google to find out if the entered query is correctly spelled
 *
 * @param string $query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function autocorrect( $query)
{
    // build url
    $url = sprintf($this->_url, urlencode($query), $this->language);

    // store html output
    $source = file_get_contents( $url);

    // strip other html data
    preg_match("'<b><i>(.*?)</i></b></a>'si", $source, $match);

    return (isset( $match[0]) ) ? strip_tags($match[0]) : FALSE;

}

}
```

then I use:

```
$word = $gdym->autocorrect($_POST['word']);
```

So, if i enter 'ipoad' it rightly thinks i mean 'ipad'

but if i enter 'ipoad 4g' it thinks that is spelt correctly.

So i figure, explode the string and do it word by word?

But when i try this it simply doesn't work - is there a better way?

here's the code i'm trying:

```
$string = $_POST['word'];

$pieces = explode(" ", $string);

foreach($pieces as $f ){

$word = $gdym->autocorrect($f);

}

if($word == false)
{
    echo '<span class="response">The word "'. $string .'" is correctly spelled</span>';
}
else
{
    echo '<span class="response">Response from Google autocorrection: ' . $word.'<span class="response">';
}
```

Comment: Do I have this right: You're scraping Google's search results to do your own auto-correct? That is hilarious. Is that normal?

Comment: Yeah its the same as using Yahoos autospell API but faster IMHO - i think ha ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your foreach loop you're overwriting the `$word` variable in each iteration. So in your check you're just checking if the last word was spelt correctly. You could use the concat operator to solve this.

```
$res = $gdym->autocorrect($f);
if ($res === false) {
    $word = $res;
    break;
} else {
    $word .= " " . $res;
}
```

Comment: @ flo if i try this with 'ipoad 4g' it returns nothing

Comment: What do you mean nothing? Add some var_dump() calls for $res so that you know what google returns for each part.

Comment: It not exactly the correct answer but it gave me thoughts to be able to fix the issue so thanks for that.